# How can I get the child key of a key in a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(
   'World'=>array(
            'Asia'=>array(
               'Japan'=>array(
                    'City'=>'Tokyo'
               )
          )
     )
);
```

In my array I am searching for a key:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
   if(is_array($item)){
      if (stripos($key, "Japan") !== false){
         echo $key;
      }
   }
}
```

The result is `Japan`.

For each key I want to check if the child key is "City". So I did the following:

```
   foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
       if(is_array($item)){
          if (stripos($key, "Japan") !== false){
             echo $key;
             foreach ($key as $k => $i) {
                if (stripos($k, "City") !== false){
                   echo "true";
               } else {
                   echo "false";
              }
          }
       }
    }
```

I expect the result `Japan` `true` or at least the result `Japan` `false` but the result is still only `Japan` I do not understand.

Comment: In your code there are syntax errors - `stripos($key, 'Japan' !== false`. Please fix'em.

Comment: I'm very confused as to what youre actually trying to do.  Also, `if (stripos($key, "Japan") !== false){` is using a string as the haystack.

Comment: @u_mulder Thank you, fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second foreach your using a single element (`$key`) while you should use a set of elements (`$array[$key]`, considering it's a multidimensional array).

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
       if(is_array($item)){
          if (stripos($key, "Japan") !== false){
             echo $key;
             foreach ($array[$key] as $k => $i) {
                if (stripos($k, "City") !== false){
                   echo "true";
               } else {
                   echo "false";
              }
          }
       }
    }
```

I'd go with a recursion algorithm to solve the problem:

```
function find_array_children_key($array, $children_key, $parent_key=''){
    $returning_value = false;
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        foreach($array as $key=>$value)
        {
            if($key===$children_key)
                $returning_value = $parent_key;
            else
                $returning_value = find_array_children_key($array,$children_key,$key);

            if($returning_value!==false)
                break;
        }
    }

    return $returning_value;
}
```

Which you'd call, for instance in your case, `find_array_children_key($array,'City')`

Comment: great! This is working! Why do I actually need `$array[$key] ` instead of `$key`

Comment: $key is only a key, a value, can be Asia or Japan or City, but $array[$key] is the value, which can be at the same time a sub-array, then your second foreach would go through it